# Issue: SqlException was unhandled

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to execute my login form using a SQL Server database.. but I'm getting an error saying

> *Incorrect syntax near '*'

The line where I am getting the error  is:

```
objda.Fill(objds, "adm");
```

and my code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int total;
    SqlConnection objc;
    string c = "data source=.; initial catalog=student; integrated security=SSPI";
    SqlDataAdapter objda;
    DataSet objds;
    SqlCommand objcmd;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (objc != null)
        {
            objc.Open();
        }
        objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * form adm where Name= ' " + textBox1.Text + "',pass = ' " + textBox2.Text + "'", objc);
        if (objc != null)
        {
            objc.Close();
        }
        objc = new SqlConnection(c);
        objcmd = new SqlCommand("search * from adm", objc);
        objda = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd.CommandText, objc);
        objds = new DataSet();
        objda.Fill(objds, "adm");

        total = Convert.ToInt32(objds.Tables["adm"].Rows.Count);
        if (total > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("welcome");
            Class1.login = textBox1.Text;
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

What should I do?

Where is the problem?

Comment: this question indicates that no search or try has been done before the asking .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgotten to place "And" between two conditions and miss spelled `form` keyword  .

```
objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from adm where Name= '" + textBox1.Text + "' And pass = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", objc);
```

by the way you should use `parameters` to [avoid `sql injection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) vulnerability

Comment: And of course, it would be **much bettter** from a security and performance point of view to use a **parametrized query** instead of concatenating together your complete SQL statement....

Comment: @marc_s : yes I have mentioned in my answer .but as the question was about the error in the query , I didn't implement it .

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the SQL injection vulnerability, the lack of using statements, and obvious incorrect syntax (missing AND, plus mispelt FROM):

You have forgotten to open the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the connection again

```
  objc.Open();
```

And change

```
select * form
```

to

```
select * from
```

Also the `AND` is missing.

Comment: isn't the object already opened... actually i tried with simple                                                                     objc.open();                                                           but it would show a NULLReference Exception unhandled error

Answer (score -3):

```
objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * form adm where Name= ' " + textBox1.Text + "',pass = ' " + textBox2.Text + "'", objc);
```

should it be:

```
objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from adm where Name= ' " + textBox1.Text + "',pass = ' " + textBox2.Text + "'", objc);
```